# Mark pipeline in red icon in Jenkins build history if one of steps is failure (but pipeline is successful)

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

is it possible to do this?

I have a pipeline, and in one of my stage that is checked - it completed successfully or unsuccessfully, and I allow the pipeline to continue even during failure - I am interested in seeing the build status on the left in the history panel, can I make it red? If pipeline get failure at this one of my stage?

This pipeline is successful finished, but inside, one of my steps is failed, how mark this pipeline in red color in history build?

[history build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eddwj.png)

Comment: Consider adding in a more clear problem statement. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can have a variable that keeps track of the failure, in the post script you can simply do `currentBuild.result ='FAILURE'`